# How to click imageSlider to go another activity?

Tags: java, android, slider

I used `com.denz.coskun.imageslider.models`
I have to click the images in this image slider and wants open another activity, what I do, anyone helps me

```
 imageSlider = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);
//now we will create a list of images for image slide

ArrayList<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();
//now we fetch url from firestore

mStore.collection("Advertisment").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()){
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot :task.getResult()){
                slideModels.add(new SlideModel(queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("url"), ScaleTypes.FIT));
                imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels, ScaleTypes.FIT);

            }
        }else {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if you are getting any errors post your logcat. it would be helpful to us to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You can read github [README.md](https://github.com/denzcoskun/ImageSlideshow)

```
     imageSlider.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(int position) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
            CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried this to home fragment. but not working

Comment: Is there any error? please share your code.